# Grouping times in Pivot Table for multiple time columns

Tags: excel, grouping, pivot-table

Right now, I have created a pivot table with rows and values as shown in the picture below. I am trying to make the row labels just a generic grouping (12 AM - 1 AM, 1 AM - 2 AM, etc.), but I didn't know any other way to do this than use Time of Day Created as my row and then right-click on one of the cells in that column and "Group."

[image: Pivot Table Values]

The result I get is the counts are all for Time of Day Created (rather than different counts dependent on the different columns). The result is in the image below:

[image: Pivot Table Result]

How can I get a pivot table that only uses the time groupings to count how many times are within that grouping for the different columns ("Updated", "Created", "Last Viewed", and "Resolved")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using `Countifs` instead to solve this solution. So the formula for the created column looked something like

```
=COUNTIFS(Data[Created (Time of Day)],">="&$B3,Data[Created (Time of Day)],"<"&$B4)
```